# Silverlight: Access element in DataForm EditTemplate by name

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, dataform

How does one access a control in a `DataForm`'s `EditTemplate` from the code behind?

The following `EditTemplate` applies:

```
<toolkit:DataForm ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=someDomainDataSource, Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <toolkit:DataForm.EditTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
            ....
            <sdk:DatePicker DisplayDate="{Binding DueDate, Mode=TwoWay}}" 
                            x:Name="dpCustomMaterialDueDate"/>
        ....
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:DataForm.EditTemplate>
</toolkit:DataForm>
```

Is it possible to access the `DatePicker` from the code-behind file using the variable name `dpCustomMaterialDueDate`? Intellisense seems unable to find it.

Also tried to access it in the `DataForm`'s `ContentLoaded` event, but no luck, i.e.

```
dataformPrintOrders.ContentLoaded += (sender, args) =>
            {
                DatePicker d = (DatePicker) 
                   dataformPrintOrders.FindNameInContent("dpCustomMaterialDuedate");
                if (d != null)
                {
                    d.DisplayDateStart = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                    d.DisplayDateEnd = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12);
                }
            };
```

The variable `d` is always null.

Answer (score 0):

You can also attached a Loaded event handler, and cast the `sender` parameter to `DatePicker`

Comment: Attach a Loaded event handler to what - the DatePicker in question?